# Word 2010 Shape Measurements or Paper Measurements or Both Are Not Accurate

Tags: microsoft-word

When I set two bar shapes to an absolute size of 5.5 inches long each and I lay them end to end they should fit exactly on a 11" wide page.  They don't. They are about 11.25 inches.  If I draw a single bar at exactly 11 inches it fits the page exactly.

Margins are all at 0. I am using these bars as layout guides. They will not be printed out but since the size is off it throws the layout off. I know Word is not ideal for layout but this should not be happening.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with the thickness of the outlines. If you make the outlines very thin, and make sure that they exactly overlap when you place the shapes next to each other, you should get the right length.

(But if you're using them to mark the exact centre of the page, there are other ways of accomplishing that. One way is to draw a perfectly straight vertical line, and then using Format > Align > Align Center (with Align to Page selected, not Align to Margin) on the line.)